# How can I access inner directories in react

Tags: reactjs

I have this folder structure but I don't exactly know how to import file from my `style` folder to for example my `PulsingCircle` component. three dots is not working, I can't just type `import CirclStyle from ".../styles/Circle.module.css";`
[image]

Comment: `../../` instead of `.../`.

Comment: Three dots (`...`) has no semantic meaning that I am aware of in import paths.  Did you mean two dots (`..`) for the parent directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from `PulsingCircle` folder import to `styles` should be:

`../../styles/Circle.module.css`

or

`./../../styles/Circle.module.css`

Comment: `./src/components/Home/PulsingCircle.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '.../../styles/Circle.module.css' in 'D:\screetest\src\components\Home'`

Comment: why it is still `.../` ?

Comment: never mind. your first example didn't work but second one worked well. thank you.

Comment: can you tell me more about these things ? I mean , each dots close 1 directory. this is the thing I know. again thank you

Comment: `./` current directory `./../` one level up from current directory, can be written with `../`
. So for example if you want to go up 2 level from current directory, you can either write `./../../` or `../../`

Comment: thank you so much 